# Problemas al leer excel(xlsx)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Tengo un problema que nunca he tenido al leer un archivo xlsx, explico lo que intento hacer.
Tengo un script puesto en un cron que descarga los archivos adjuntos de una cuenta de email y luego lee la informacion de los archivos y los guarda en una base de datos, pero mi problema viene al leer un archivo que me llega de una persona en concreto.
Intento leer este tipo de archivo con la libreria PHPExcel y no me deja leer el excel, pero en cambio si abro el excel y simplemente le doy a guardar y ejecuto el script me lo lee perfectamente y claro quiero que esto no dependa de una persona fisica.
Alguna idea del porque?
He de decir que el script lee varios archivos excels(xlsx) pero el que comento no me deja es como si estuviera vacio, ya que ni error me da la libreria.
Ojala me puedan ayudar, gracias!!

Este es parte de mi código para leer el excel:

```
try
{  
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);  
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{  
 die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());  
}  

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);  

foreach($sheetData as $rec)  
{  
 echo $rec['A'];  
}
```

PD. Este es el excel: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wHj4NL0iV-czFiMHl0R01yODA/view

Comment: Ya revisaste si el  archivo de esa persona. no es un html,  csv en realidad ?. o talvez la codificación es diferente a la que tienes ?. o se realizo en una versión mas moderna de excel. ?

Comment: **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: @SergioCauich el archivo es un xlsx, lo de la versión mas moderna no lo tengo claro pero sería mucha la diferencia? he adjuntodo el archivo y parte del código que utilizo para leer el xlsx. Saludos!